# sonar's code coverage using ANt (build.xml)

Tags: java, xml, ant, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to use my junit test for sonar's code coverage. I am using Ant. I am trying to update build.xml like this:

```
<!-- ========= Define SonarQube Scanner for Ant Target ========= -->
    <target name="sonar" depends="compile">
        <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml">
            <!-- Update the following line, or put the "sonar-ant-task-*.jar" file in your "$HOME/.ant/lib" folder -->
            <classpath path="/lib/sonar-ant-task-2.0.jar" />
        </taskdef>
        <!-- Execute SonarQube Scanner for Ant Analysis -->
        <sonar:sonar />
    </target>
```

But it is showing "resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml" not found. I have sonar-ant-task-2.0.jar in my lib folder. and I am using intellij.

This . are the properties i added in build.xml

```
<property name="sonar.projectKey" value="org.codehaus.sonar:example-java-ant" />
    <property name="sonar.projectName" value="SIML project" />
    <property name="sonar.projectVersion" value="1.0" />
    <property name="sonar.test" value="test" />
```

Please help :) :)
And let me know if you need any other information to make question clear. :)

Comment: Are you sure, the path to your JAR is `/lib/sonar-ant-task-2.0.jar` and not `lib/sonar-ant-task-2.0.jar` without leading slash?

Comment: ohh thanks you :) it solved the problem.  but 
        <sonar:sonar />
this is still not resolved

Comment: Did you declare the `sonar` namespace in the root node like `<project name="Project name" xmlns:sonar="antlib:org.sonar.ant">`?

Comment: This is sufficient for sonar coverage?. Because after all this coverage is showing 0%.

Comment: I additionally declared some sonar properties like `sonar.host.url` with the URL to the Sonar server, `sonar.source` with the path to the Java sources, `sonar.sourceEncoding`, `sonar.java.binaries`, `sonar.java.libraries`, etc.

Comment: Is this issue resolved?